# Protobuf: Understanding the compiled output of proto files

Tags: c++, protoc, protocol-buffers

**Hi All,
I am new to the protobuf. I am trying to understand the basics here.
I have created the sample proto file as `Test.proto` in directory `/path/to/Directory/`:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }**

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}
```

and compiled it with

```
 protoc -I=/path/to/Directory/ --cpp_out=/path/to/Directory/ /path/to/Directory/Test.proto
```

This created 2 files `Test.pb.h` and `Test.pb.cc`. Now I can see that there are different functions in the class `Person`. Let's just take the function *(derived from the line `required string name = 1;` of `Test.proto` file)*

Now the compiler does it's thing and gives these various functions:

```
bool has_name() const;
void clear_name();
static const int kNameFieldNumber = 1;
const ::std::string& name() const;
void set_name(const ::std::string& value);
void set_name(::std::string&& value);
void set_name(const char* value);
void set_name(const char* value, size_t size);
::std::string* mutable_name();
::std::string* release_name();
void set_allocated_name(::std::string* name);
```

**Now my question is:** Where can I find the descriptions of each functions and what they do?

Comment: in specific I want to know what `mutable_name()` and `release_name()` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starting point is [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/) (static code) and [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated) (generated code). The latter includes overviews of what you ask in your "in specific" - search for: `string* mutable_foo()` and `string* release_foo()` (noting that they are duplicated for proto2 vs proto3).

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated) of C++ Generated Code:

> `string* mutable_foo()`: Returns a pointer to the mutable string
>   object that stores the field's value. If the field was not set prior
>   to the call, then the returned string will be empty (not the default
>   value). After calling this, `has_foo()` will return `true` and `foo()`
>   will return whatever value is written into the given string.
>
> `string* release_foo()`: Releases the ownership of the field and
>   returns the pointer of the string object. After calling this, caller
>   takes the ownership of the allocated string object, `has_foo()` will
>   return false, and `foo()` will return the default value.

You can find the descriptions of the rest of the functions in the same page.